# Is validation necessary with TCP?

Tags: tcp

I had to implement an application which in very short, sent packets every few seconds to a server, when the server received them it send a response to the client which only then proceeded to send another packet. This sounds all good but we were using TCP and the responses came as soon as the server got the packet and not post-processing or anything like that. So that makes me wonder, why would you do something like this? The client had a queue where I kept all the packets and did something like this:

```
try {
    send packet // exception is thrown if connection is lost
    remove packet from queue
} catch exception {
    try to reconnect 
}
```

so in this case the packet gets removed from the queue only if the *send* was successful.

Any idea about this? Is this best practice? I would appreciate if someone could clear this for me.

Thanks

Comment: Q: What's your question?  Would it be better to "fire and forget" (rather than maintain a queue)?  A: Quite possibly.  Would it be better to use UDP instead of TCP (as long as we're keeping a queue and presumably managing retries)?  A: Quite possibly.  Is problematic to detect "send" errors (without some kind of "ACK")?  A: Yes.  The answer to any of these (potential) questions is: "It depends". ;)  IMHO...

Comment: TCP guarantees transport and ordering. so with UDP you would possibly lose the ordering and you would have to do the resending and reordering and fragmentation by yourself.

Comment: If you only need to know that the connection is up , there is an option called TCP_KEEPALIVE , which will send packets to keep the connection alive and time it out if they are lost.This will naturally not guarantee that the software in the other end is working, just that the TCP connection is still alive.

Comment: Also are the queries idempotent? ie. can you just resend them even though they were already processed without doing any damage? this will have an effect on your design.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about how the server handles them, but the packets have a time-stamp and shouldn't mess up anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sending isn't enough in some cases. If it's absolutely critical that the data you're shoving out the door MUST be received, then you should wait for an acknowledgement that the packet was received/processed by the remote end.

Even if the network-level stuff works perfectly and the packets arrive at the destination, that destination machine might still crash or otherwise lose the data. If you remove-on-send, then that data's gone. Waiting for acknowledgements from the remote end would at least give you the ability to resend packets that were corrupted/lost.

Comment: Do you think it's likely that the server might crash and the connection to remain alive? Maybe if it's held in a thread somehow?

Comment: the software might fail and not die. for example it might deadlock

Comment: You're very right. I looked at this from a very naive perspective. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to put the packets into a queue and send them. After sending move them into a "pending" queue. Once the other end has *processed* them, you mark them as completed. Then you are up against other problems. What if the other end processes them but the ack never gets to your end? This is a relatively researched problem and I suggest you research distributed transactions and two phase commit, if you need to be sure.